# What is the equivalent of -webkit-gradient for Opera browser?

Tags: css, webkit, opera

I would like to know what is the equivalent of  -webkit-gradient for Opera browser

```
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(2%,#e5153b), color-stop(8%,#d91438), color-stop(100%,#87001e));
```

Solution for Opera Presto (my case):

background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e5153b 2%,#d91438 8%,#87001e 100%);

Comment: FYI. Opera Presto is not supported any more, Opera has moved to the same engine powering Chrome (Blink).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`-o-linear-gradient`](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css3-linear-gradients/) for opera, for more info you can refer [here](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/).

But if you want, simply using `linear-gradient` is sufficient, if you are not planning to support vintage versions.

Answer (score 3):

Opera [currently supports standard `linear-gradient`](http://caniuse.com/#search=grad).  Since Opera is now a webkit browser I would expect either `-webkit-gradient` or `-webkit-linear-gradient` (or both) to work, but you don't need it for newer versions.  Before Opera was Webkit you would use `-o-linear-gradient`.